# Is there an API to add a domain to the approved domain list?

Tags: api, tinymce

We offer vanity URLs to our customers. For each customer that needs a vanity URL, we manually add the domain to the approved domain list. This is a process we wish to automate.

Do you offer an API to add domains?
If not, do you have plans to do so in the future?

Thanks!

Note: we tried to find an API to add domains in your API documentation, but we couldn't find one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

We do not provide an API to add domains to the list of valid domains.  If you are a commercial customer please contact us via support and we can discuss alternatives that might address this issue.